# Calculating probability of two random variables

Tags: self-study, random-variable

I'm having trouble calculating the probability of two random variables. A question on an exam review is P(X+Y>38). I know how to do this problem with just one variable, using z scores, but i'm not sure how to approach this with two variables. We are given standard deviation and mean.

Comment: Hey Alice, welcome on Stack Exchange. Without knowing the distribution this question is hard to answer. If the random variables are (as I assume) normally distributed and independent you can use that if $X\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2), Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ it holds that: $X+Y\sim N( \mu_1+\mu_2, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$, now you simply calculate the z-Score for this new normal distribution and derive the probability

Comment: @Sebastian we know its a normal distribution and we know they are independent as well.

Comment: Ok. Do you know how to answer the qestion then? If not please ask

Comment: @Sebastian the standard deviations are 2 and 6 with means 10 and 20. So we can just do N(10 + 20, 4+36)?

Comment: @Sebastian does this same rule follow for X-Y?

Comment: Yes exactly: For the difference: $X-Y\sim N(\mu_1-\mu_2, \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$ (Because $X-Y= X+(-Y)$ and if $Y\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ then $-Y\sim N(-\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$